# How to insert new string to DB by button Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

How to insert new string to DB by button Django and get id new record

```
<a href="{% url "main:create_bd_line" %}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Начать</button></a>
```

```
def create_bd_line(request):
    user_group = request.user.groups.values_list()
    university = user_group[0][1]
     num = Answers.objects.all().count() # number of strings in table
```

model.py

```
class Answers(models.Model):
id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
id_univ = models.TextField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
q1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
q2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
q3 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
q4 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
q5 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
q6 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: What is the model you want to add a record to that table? what do you want to add as a new record?

Comment: @Javad add model, insert null record for all columns

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I do this and its work

```
num = Answers.objects.all().count() # number of strings in table    
new_user_answer = num + 1
        new_line = Answers(id=new_user_answer)
        new_line.save()
```